# Screen & Audio capture and push to specific twitch RTSP server

Tags: c++

Wonder if there is a code to record screen or window with audio and push it to specific twitch RTSP server instead of OBS or Streamlabs ..
thanks for helping

Comment: You would have to write quite a lot of code to do that. First you would need to record target window (I've used BitBlt [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-bitblt] in the past to do so, but there is probably more convenient ways since BitBlt forces your to have the window you're recording in front) then send it to twitch with the right encoding. Are you trying to do something specific? maybe it would be easier to write some OBS plugin if you're trying to do something specific with the recorded stream.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.